# My JFrame wont become the size that i set

Tags: java, swing

no matter what i try my jframe window wont resize,its either really small or just goes full screen, i dont know what must resize either if possible could you help with that too

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class TheHundeler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.print("java poes");
        JFrame Frame = new JFrame();
        CalculaterContructer builder1 = new CalculaterContructer();

        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel board = new JPanel();
        board.setLayout(null);
        builder1.buttonBuild(board);//this function has no effect on the end result of the size change 
 //not working
        board.setSize(1000, 1000);
        Frame.add(board);
        Frame.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
        Frame.pack();
        Frame.setVisible(true);



    }

}
```

Comment: Try using `setPreferredSize()` instead. Also I'd recommend `camelCasing` your variables (`Frame` should be `frame`).

Comment: 1) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: .. 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 4) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you let the panel dictate the size. That way, the frame borders won't affect it and the actual space you see will reflect the dimensions.

For the panel, do a `setPreferredSize()` of your size.  Then add it to the Frame and do a `frame.pack()`.

And after `pack` if you do `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null)` it will center it on the screen.